How to disable the navigation drawer on login fragment?
How to disable the navigation drawer together with hamburger button and toolbar while the user is on login fragment (or sign up fragment)? After the user login in app, I want to enable the navigation drawer and the others.
activity_main.xml

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
                android:id="@+id/materialToolbar"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                app:navigationIcon="@drawable/menu_sandwich_button" />

        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation_view_menu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/menu_header"
        app:menu="@menu/menu">

    </com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

onCreate()
 setSupportActionBar(materialToolbar);
 getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);


You can disable it like this:
navDrawer.close();
nawDrawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);


Hello! Where to set this? In overridden onStart() method from login fragment?

onViewCreated()

But after the user is logged in the navigation drawer is still hidden. The user must to enter again to the app to see the menu

show your code or i can only speculate
